# How to set Info.Plist to get AWSSNS.defaultSNS work

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, swift2

I'm getting an error while I'm trying to get defaultSNS from AWSSNS. It says :

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The service configuration
is `nil`. You need to configure `Info.plist` or set `defaultServiceConfiguration` 
before using this method.'
```

I'm working on a sample file downloaded from MobileHub integration page, and my code is placed inside PushNotificationViewController. It is as below :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let pushManager: AWSPushManager = AWSPushManager.defaultPushManager()
    pushManager.delegate = self
    pushManager.registerForPushNotifications()
    pushNotificationSwitch.on = pushManager.enabled
    if let topicARNs = pushManager.topicARNs {
        pushManager.registerTopicARNs(topicARNs)
    }

    let someDict:[String:String] = ["CustomUserData":"This is test data"]
    var attr = AWSSNSSetEndpointAttributesInput()
    attr.attributes = someDict
    attr.endpointArn = "arn:aws:sns:xxxxxxxx"
    let defSns = AWSSNS.defaultSNS() <-- Error is here
    defSns.setEndpointAttributes(attr) 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the solution. Just copy paste the same values from PushManager and changed PushManager to SNS. Voila, works like a charm.